# How to get the first instance of a column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table of 21 million rows with dates stretching all the way from 2009.

For the purpose of this question, only three columns are concerned. It has a date column (called settlement date) and one date can occur on thousands of rows. The other column is Net Sales and this has dollar values and the final column is fiscal year. I did a calculated column to find the cumulative values:

```
Commulative = 
CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'IP Net Sales'[Net Sales] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLEXCEPT ( 'IP Net Sales', 'IP Net Sales'[Fiscal Year] ),
            'IP Net Sales'[Settlement  Date] <= EARLIER ( 'IP Net Sales'[Settlement Date])
        )
    )
```

However, I have ran into the scenario below where on the same day, I am getting a value that sums up all the Net Sales that happened on that day and this value is duplicated for the entire day. This itself is fine, however, when i do a line graph, it sums all these values whereas i only want one instance of this cumulative value per day. How to go on about doing?

[image]

Comment: why using a column instead of a measure

Comment: Use AVERAGE for line chart. This will keep the value same.

Comment: Would measure solve the trick?

Comment: So stupid of me, thanks guys. If you can post the answer, happy to to solve this question.